# Julia Concatenating dataframes in loop

Tags: loops, dataframe, concatenation, julia

I have files in folder that I want to read all at once, bind and make new dataframe.

Code:

```
using CSV, DataFrames

path="somepath"

files=readdir(path)

d=DataFrame()

for file=files

    x=CSV.read(file)

    d=vcat(d,x)

end
```

Produces:

```
Error: UndefVarError: d not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `append!` in such cases (change allowing this approach is on master but is not released yet):

```
d=DataFrame()
for file=files
    append!(d, CSV.read(file))
end
```

or, if you want to use `vcat` (this option will use a bit more memory):

```
reduce(vcat, [CSV.read(file) for file in files])
```

The original code should be rewritten as:

```
d=DataFrame()
for file=files
    x=CSV.read(file)
    global d=vcat(d,x)
end
```

(note `global` in front of `d`) but this is not a recommended way to perform this operation.